# 'Connection to Podio API failed: [35] Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.podio.com:443

Tags: ssl, podio

Using simple **podio api** things, but overnight I have this message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PodioConnectionError' with message
>   'Connection to Podio API failed: [35] Unknown SSL protocol error in
>   connection to api.podio.com:443

No SSL have changed from my part, and as long as I know, podio api is the same since 2015...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> No SSL have changed from my part, and as long as I know, podio api is the same since 2015...

It is very likely that you are using some old TLS stack with no support for TLS 1.2 or that you've explicitly setup your system to use TLS 1.0 only. From [Podio Help Centre](https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003048772-API-Security-Update):

> API Security Update
>    Upcoming change for developers using Podio's API 
> ....
> What you need to **do by 27 June 2018**
>   Ensure you are using **TLS 1.1 as a minimum**, though we **recommend upgrading to TLS 1.2**.  This applies to private, public and partner applications connecting to the Podio API.

Comment: Um... just checked and it looks like my domain is tls 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 compliant... verified through an online checker...

Comment: @Puraenvidia_: if you access an API you are the client. In this case it does not matter if the web server on your domain can do TLS 1.2, what matters is if your API client supports TLS 1.2 when connecting to the API server.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers...weird thing is I've checked, and the server from where I run the podio API scripts (from a local install) do support TLS 1.1, even 1.2... And, obviousl, podio supports TLS 1.1 too...

I'd ask my hosting provider about it I guess...

Comment: @Puraenvidia_: again, it does not matter what the system supports in the role of a web server. It only matters what your specific client program (whatever this is) supports for TLS protocols. One can have various TLS clients with different TLS stacks and different settings on the same system so you need to look at your specific client.

Comment: Well.. in the end it was a  hosting execution environment issue... Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Podio have disabled TLS 1.0 - the last bit was done yesterday.
TLS 1.0 was deprecated a while ago, and it's end of life was set to June 2018.

Details are here: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003048772-API-Security-Update

Podio will also disable TLS 1.1 some day, so if you are upgrading - move to latest TLS 1.2.

Comment: If you're using the .NET SDK alongside .NET 4.5, you may see exceptions like "Object reference not set [...]" - this is because of the above. You need to set to at least `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;` and the exception will go away.