# Podio - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, podio

Since today we have been receiving the following error when making API requests to Podio:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
>       current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about 
>       the error and where it originated in the code.

Stack Trace:

```
Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection 
was forcibly closed by the remote host

[SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +82
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +232
   System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +13
   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +119

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +623
   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +64

[HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Net.Http.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext() +948
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   PodioAPI.<Request>d__36`1.MoveNext() +626
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   PodioAPI.<Get>d__31`1.MoveNext() +307
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   PodioAPI.Services.<GetItem>d__6.MoveNext() +277
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
```

Please, could someone shed some light on this issue? We haven't changed anything in our code. This has basically just started happening. Tried from multiple devices and locations, so think something must have changed at Podio's end. We are using the libraries from here - http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Connection to Podio API failed: \[35\] Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.podio.com:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214173/connection-to-podio-api-failed-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podio have disabled TLS 1.0 - the last bit was done yesterday.
TLS 1.0 was deprecated a while ago, and it's end of life was set to June 2018.

Details are here: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003048772-API-Security-Update

Podio will also disable TLS 1.1 some day, so if you are upgrading - move to latest TLS 1.2.

Also, new versions of nuget packages are now published:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio.Async/

Answer (score 3):

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51229798/10018200) if your application targeting Dotnet Framework between 4.0 < 4.6, then you need to set the default SecurityProtocol to at least Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.1 ie

> SecurityProtocolType.Tls11

ref: [An application targeting .NET 4.0 can still support up to TLS 1.2 if .NET 4.5 is installed in the same environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28333370/10018200)